# @DataProvider and @BeforeMethod order

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, testng

What method is invoked first in a test class with testng annotations:

> - annotated with @DataProvider
> - annotated with @BeforeMethod

?

During my testing I found the order: 1. @DataProvider 2. @BeforeMethod

But my @DataProvider uses the variable that will be initialized only in @BeforeMethod.
What workaround may be the best here?

My case is the following:

```
class Test 
  @BeforeClass
    //here I initialize pages (pageobjects in context of selenium)
  @BeforeMethod
    //here i 'get' the page I want (and the one i'll use in dataprovider)

  @Test(dataProvider = "dp")
    //my test goes here...

  @DataProvider
  dp
    //here I use page. The page may be 'usable' only if it was already 'get'.
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with your @DataProvider?  I've never had an instance where I've needed to create data after the page was loaded.

Comment: In DataProvider I want to gather data from the page to be tested inside the test. That's why I need page to be already 'get'.

Comment: Can you post the code for dp, beforemethod, beforeclass? Also why cant you initialize that variable in the either beforeclass or dp method?

Comment: Why not just put your get in your @DataProvider then?

Comment: Thanks, MrTi and TestAutomationEngr, to put either in beforeclass or dp method are the options I also thought about... I asked the question to find maybe some better solutions... So far I put 'get' in dataprovider... 
One more thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `@BeforeMethod` annotation, make it `private`, and call it explicitly from the data provider.